# How to generate a new .xproj-based .NET Core project on Linux?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, asp.net-core, dnx

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 box and I'm looking to generate a new .xproj-based .NET Core project. On Windows, you would do this from Visual Studio by hitting *Ctrl + Shift + N* and creating a new *Class Library (Package)* project. My question is, since Visual Studio isn't available for Linux, what would be the equivalent for that platform?

Also, it would be nice if it was doable from the terminal, since my Linux installation doesn't have a GUI. Is there (for example) a Yeoman generator of some sort for this?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I think you just need project.json (which btw. will also work in VS)

Comment: Did you look at the [OmniSharp documentation](https://github.com/OmniSharp/generator-aspnet)? It seems like yeoman will generate a class library based on the ASPNET/Templates project, which is [xproj based](https://github.com/aspnet/Templates/tree/dev/src/BaseTemplates/ClassLibrary).

Comment: Why do you need xproj on non-windows and how are you planning to keep it up to date with your project.json file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is step by step tutorial of creating C# project from scratch with Visual Studio Code: http://michaelcrump.net/creating-and-debugging-console-apps-with-vscode/

Answer (score 1):

*.xproj* files are Visual Studio project files for project.json based projects. You only need such a project file if you want to use the project in Visual Studio.

Otherwise, the `project.json` is all you need. I recommend you to check out the [Getting Started](https://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/) guide of the dotnet CLI, which explains how to start a new project.json based project.